# is reboot needed after editing etc/cron.d/php5 file?

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I checked the file in etc/cron/php5 and I found this scheduling
09,39 * * * * ....

I edited the etc/cron.d/php5 file so that it runs each 4 hours

05 */4 * * * .....

and saved it.

Does this new update become available immediatly or do I have to reboot something to activate the new scheduling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply No. Until unless you edit the file using crontab -e command.

If you edit the file through -e command than you need to restart.

Comment: @agodoo did u get the point

Comment: I edited the file using nano and saved the file at the end of the edit. So if I got it I don't need to do nothing more

Comment: Yes you are right for the save hand refresh it just a suggestion.  And if the answer help u mark as accepted it will help for others. @agodoo

Answer (score 0):

If everything is configured correctly,  you don't need a reboot to get this work on the new schedule.